# how to delete data from fields

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
Private Sub BtnDelete_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnDelete.Click
        Dim cash As Integer
        Dim result As String
        Try
            With com
                .Connection = con
                .CommandText = "DELETE cash_advance =@cash_advance FROM employees_records " & _
              "WHERE id_no= '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
                result = com.ExecuteNonQuery
                If result = 0 Then
                    com.Parameters.Remove(New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("cash_advance", cash))
                Else
                    MsgBox("Deleted")

                End If
            End With
```

I want to delete just one fields from my table.

Comment: Did you want delete rows where `cash_advance =@cash_advance` ?

Comment: Remove `try ..catch` around your code - and you will get a error with explanation what wrong. You have `try`, and I assume your `catch` part is empty - that why you do not getting error....

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete a *field,* you can only delete rows.

If you want to *empty* a field of its value, you should set it to zero, the empty string or NULL depending on its type, something like:

```
update employees_records set cash_advance = 0 where id_no = 42
```

This will set the `cash_advance` field back to zero, on the assumption that it's a dollar value. If that assumption is incorrect, simply change the value you're setting it to.

---

There are some other things you can do to assist in isolating these types of problems.

1. Print out (or otherwise log) the command string before you attempt to execute it. A significant number of times, it's due to a badly formed query or dodgy `where` clause.
2. Execute that *exact* same query from the database itself rather than your code.
3. Ensure that, if you're catching exceptions, you log the fact - sometimes the problem is a `try { ... } catch {}` construct.

Comment: @Chris, "it didn't work" is not really a helpful problem report :-) In what way did it not work? Didn't update? Updated to wrong value? Crashed program? The update is the correct way to change a field so, if it didn't work, the first thing I'd suspect is that you're not quite doing it right.

Comment: it didn't update THE CASH ADVANCE is still there 
  With com
                .Connection = con
                .CommandText = "UPDATE employees_records SET  cash_advance = 0" & _
              "WHERE id_no= '" & TextBox1.Text & "' "

                result = com.ExecuteNonQuery

                If result = 0 Then

                    com.Parameters.Add(New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("cash_advance", cash))

                Else

                    MsgBox("DELETED")